# Validate field on certain contexts or no context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am working on a rails project, and am validating fields using different contexts.  Is there a way I can set a field to validate such that it will be validated on some specific context, and will also be validated if there is no context passed in? Accordingly, if a unspecified context is passed in, it should not be validated.  Pseudo example:

```
# using nil to indicate it should be validated if there is no context, I know this is not the proper syntax
validates :name, on: [:foo, nil]
```

```
# should validate
form.valid?(:foo)

# should validate
form.valid?

# should NOT validate
form.valid?(:bar)
```

Comment: As far as I can tell validation contexts can't do what you want...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think validations will work in that exact way however there are alternatives.

#### 1. Add an additional attribute that will not be persisted.

Add `attr_accessor :context` to your form model and set it using `form.context = :foo` before you check `form.valid?`.
You validation would then become a [conditional](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-proc-with-if-and-unless) `validates :name, if: -> {context == :foo}`

Pros: Super simple to implement

Cons: Testing becomes a little more complex; Difficult to read when adding more `validate ... if` statements

#### 2. Introduce a second model

Assuming you have a `Form` model just now, you could introduce a `FooForm` which inherits from `Form` like `FooForm < Form`. Your `FooForm` can have the validation line declared and your regular `Form` does not.
This approach would allow you to expand out in the future as presumably if there are differing validation requirements now, then functionality will likely diverge too.
The view layer in Rails won't mind if you create a form using the `FooForm` or the `Form` model.
A drawback of this is that `form_with` or `form_for` will point to differing paths by default i.e. `foo_forms/:id/` and `forms/:id`, this can be overwritten in the view or "somewhere" in the model

Pros: Testing separate behaviours on separate models is obvious and rational; Simple to expand to `BooForm` and `BazForm` etc.

Cons: More models to manage; Form helpers default paths can trip you up.